# Go version returns unknown, gccgo fails

Tags: go, gcc, gccgo

I installed gccgo using:

```bash
sudo pacman -S gcc-go
```

When I tried building my code using `go build -buildvcs=false -compiler gccgo .`, the following error was returned:

```bash
# github.com/CompeyDev/nemo/prisma/db
gccgo: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program go1
compilation terminated.
note: module requires Go 1.19
```

So, I ran `go version` which returned `go version unknown linux/amd64`; note the "**unknown**". I have no clue how the version can return unknown.

Thanks to @JimB pointing out how the arch gcc-go package was compatible with version 1.18 only, I was able to downgrade go, and this fixed the compilation issue. However, now I have a new error:

```bash
# github.com/CompeyDev/nemo/prisma/db
gccgo: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program go1
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Why are you using gccgo? The go tool probably can't get the version from gccgo, but are you sure you can install gccgo with a version compatible with go1.19 in the first place, the arch gcc-go package claims 1.18.

Comment: @JimB, You're right -- I hadn't realized that gcc-go was compatible with 1.18 only. But now I get another error, updating the question accordingly.

Comment: gccgo is going to be harder to debug, can you build your project with the standard toolchain to check for other errors?

Comment: The standard go build command does not exactly cause errors, that's that odd thing.

Comment: Well if the project builds with the gc compiler, then you at least know it's something specific to gccgo. Maybe try with the `-x` flag to see what exactly is failing? Do you actually need gccgo at all?

Comment: The main reason why I need gccgo is for the binary size, as normal go builds are comparatively larger than gccgo builds. Size is of essence. I've actually run the command with the `-x` flag, but it does not exactly display any errors except for the one mentioned above, which is why I decided to seek help.

Comment: The lack of error sounds like it’s killed externally. Are you running on a small instance where you could be running out of memory?

Comment: I have around 4 GB of memory, I think that should be enough.